# Changing default location of CQL scripts in DataStax Dev Center

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Currently, DataStax's Dev Center saves CQL scripts to:

- scratchpads: `user-home /.devcenter/DevCenter/.default`
- CQL scripts: `user-home /.devcenter/DevCenter/CQLScripts`

Does anyone know of a way to change this default save directory? The 'Preferences' window does not seem to have this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to change the CQL script file location, but improved file management is planned.